# How to create an object dynamically?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how can an object be created with code. I have started with something like this

```
object ns = new PictureBox();
ns.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.myImage;
```

But the compiler gives me an error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'BackgroundImage' and no extension method 'BackgroundImage' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And if I remove last line, it compiles but nothing appears on the window.

Comment: or simply use `var ns = ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're really asking is how to add controls to a form at run time.  The comments on your question are correct as far as what you've actually asked, but you're still not going to see anything on the form.  To do that, you actually have to add the control to the form:

```
var ns = new PictureBox();

ns.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.myImage;
this.Controls.Add(ns);
```

By the way, is there a particular reason that you're setting the `BackgroundImage` property and not the `Image` property?

Comment: Hi there! Thank you very much for your reply! I am newbie in C#, and it seems there is no room for starters here on stackoverflow. Every time I ask something easy I get down votes and down reputation... sight. Anyway, yes, there is a reason for that, I use `BackgroundImage` so that I can also set `backgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch`, and the image will.. well.. stretch.. to the picturebox size. I couldn't find any way to do this with the image property... Thanks again for your prompt reply! I would vote you up if I could, but asking this question took my reputation away and now I can't.

Comment: You should be setting the `Image` property and using the `SizeMode` property to control the relationship between the size of the control and the size of the image.  `StretchImage` will force the image to take on the same dimensions as the control.

Comment: You don't upvote an answer to your own question.  An upvote is worth 10 points but an accepted answer is worth 15.  You accept an answer to your question, which you have already done.